# How can I pretty print erb in BBedit indenting rails tags and not just markup?

Tags: format, ruby-on-rails, indentation, bbedit

I want to re-indent my code but the rails tags `<% foo %>` get aligned to the left with no indentation. What I'm using is:

> markup > utilities > format > pretty print

Does anyone know if there is a way to reconfigure this behavior?

---

UPDATE:

I just found this out but cant seem to get it working:

> "The 'Pretty print' option for Markup -> Utilities -> Format is now implemented internally using a Dreamweaver-style source format profile. This affords slightly prettier output than was possible before. Advanced users can override the factory format profile by placing an appropriately constructed file at ~/Library/Application
>   Support/BBEdit/SourceFormat.profile."

I opened the bbedit app package, found the file, copied it to the folder indicated in "application support" and tweaked the desired indentation width just as a test before touching anything else, and it doesnt seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I cant get it to work for some reason but as mentioned above this is obviously the way:

~/Library/Application Support/BBEdit/SourceFormat.profile